# VS Code not picking up args list from launch.json

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a basic python file that I'm experimenting with. I want to launch it with two args in vs code. I've opened the launch.json file from the command window (ctrl+shift+p) but on each run it fails to pick up my args list. What is going on?

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": ["4", "2"]
    }
]
}
```

The main program:

```
import sys

def add(num1=0, num2=0):
    return int(num1) + int(num2)

def sub(num1=0, num2=0):
    return int(num1) - int(num2)

def main():
    #Assuming our inputs are valid numbers
    print ("args: ",sys.argv)
    addition = add(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    print (addition)
    subtraction = sub(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    print (subtraction)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When executing in VS Code, the traceback is:

```
>     args:  ['c:/Users/chicago/OneDrive/Documents/Code/Python/debugging/pdb 1.py']
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\chicago\OneDrive\Documents\Code\Python\debugging\pdb
> 1.py", line 18, in <module>
>     main()   File "c:\Users\chicago\OneDrive\Documents\Code\Python\debugging\pdb
> 1.py", line 12, in main
>     addition = add(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]) IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: how are you running the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its probable that vscode isn't picking up your launch configurations. Just a few sanity checks:

Did you confirm that launch.json is located in .vscode/ ?

In addition - did you make sure that you have the right configuration selected when you go to run? In this case: "Python: Current File".

[launch configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdsFY.png)

Comment: Thanks and resolved. I realised that I need to be in the "Debug" sidebar area. Instead I was running with "Debug file in terminal" where it does not pickup the launch.json file. Appears the two are not related. Do you know the difference between the two?

Comment: Yikes I'm late to this - my bad. Adding my answer for anyone in the future coming across this thread. The "Debug file or Run python file" commands just load the current file in the editor into an ad-hoc python REPL and runs the output in the terminal. Running from the debug menu runs the entire python application through the intrepreter. When using just one file - there's not much difference. However, in larger applications, using the debug menu allows for pre build steps, post build steps. custom python virtual env configuration etc.

Comment: @Dan, You should add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me,provided you already have a launch.json file, press **Ctrl+Shift+D**, Select Python Debugger, Click on "**Open launch.json**" icon (crank icon), make sure the you have:

"name": "Python Debugger: Current File",

Note:No other name will work, and you have your arguments:

"args": [
"--config",
"config.cnf",
"--configPath",
"configArchive/cc/"
]

Then it should pick up your arguments

There is also an option, when you open your python file, you need to select "Python Debugger: Debug using launch.json"

(I see it was indicated above as well in comments :-))

Shortcut key: **F5**